# How can find the PolicyGroup?

Tags: security, axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2012, policy

I need to check about the Policies, and I need to get more info about *PolicyGroup*

[image: Group]

Do you know where can I manage these PolicyGroup? Are there any parameter to activate these?
Please, could me give me some info about these area

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The **PolicyGroup** property is set by a drop-down list that contains the security policy group names that the system administrator has created.

The system administrator or developer can create security policy groups. This property can be used by administrators and developers to quickly identify groups of related security policies. The system does not use this property during run time.

[link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamicsax-2012/developer/security-policies-properties#security-policy-properties)

Comment: While correct, it is somehow unusual that you, the developer, can write anything in the field and it is accepted. Next time what you wrote will show up in the lookup.
The lookup is a "group by" of all the policy groups entered.